# How to hide the Tabs in Hawtio? Also, how to stop the default landing on ActiveMQ after connecting to remote server?

Tags: angularjs, server, activemq-classic, hawtio

I have 2 questions here:

**1. How to hide unwanted Tabs in the Tab navigator of Hawtio?**

There are other tabs on home page as well as Connection page of Hawtio. I want to remove few and keep only my custom tabs.

**2. By default, after connecting to remote server, it lands on Active MQ page. 
Here, I want it to land on my custom plugin html.**

I know the URL which is being hit for landing on ActiveMQ page. But I want to figure out from where it is being hit. If not that, I want to find out how can I pass my own URL (for landing on custom Plugin html, which opens only when I click on the custom Tab.)

The changes need to be done at the code level.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1.

In the preference you can disable/enable plugins, and change the order they are listed.

Ad 2.

In the preference you can reorder the plugins so your custom plugin is listed first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to do it programmatically.  I dont want the end user to do the work in Preferences. It needs to be done through the code itself.

Comment: You can package your custom version of hawtio where you setup which tabs are enabled as you wish. You can do that in the vendor.js file - https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-static-site/src/main/webapp/vendor.js. Ask on #hawtio on IRC or its community how to do that for more details.

Comment: Hey Claus, Thanks for the help. Have posted the question accordingly on Hawtio google group. 1+ for your valuable comment.