# Hawtio read only options based on roles enabled

Tags: hawtio

I am trying to integrate Hawtio with my Java applications.  I have an use case to display few features to level-2 support and few more to level-1 support,etc by enabling roles.

I am able keep separate creds for level-1/2 by using tomcat roles but I couldn't control the tabs likes Thread/dashboard,etc.

Is there anyway.  I am using Hawtio-1.5.2-offline as a war format.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to control shows/hides of top-level tabs based on user roles.

You can show/hide top-level tabs on a per-user basis, or just customise the complete package itself. See this Q&A for more info:
[How to hide the Tabs in Hawtio? Also, how to stop the default landing on ActiveMQ after connecting to remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996934/how-to-hide-the-tabs-in-hawtio-also-how-to-stop-the-default-landing-on-activem)

Comment: This helps.  Able to disable/enable tabs via preferences.  But unable to configure as user-wise since the same option is reflecting for all the users.  Do we need to explicitly mention anything in hawtio/WEB-INF/web.xml to differentiate the user?